# XBee connected to an Android phone

Tags: java, android, serial-port, xbee

I'm trying to write code to connect my Android phone with an [XBee-PRO](https://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-pro-xsc).

Here's my code:

```
XBee xbee = new XBee();
try {
    xbee.open("COM22", 115200);
    // ..
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: How do you know that is not working? All you are doing is opening a port - are you getting an error message?  Try the rest of the code and post what error you get

Comment: How are the XBee and the phone connected physically?

Comment: actually i got a code that's work fine with the computer and the xbee as a java project but when i convert it as an android project using eclipse it's give me error in reading the default port of the phone

Comment: my code came from here https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use a different name for the serial port, something along the lines of `/dev/ttyS##` where `##` is the serial port number.  You'll have to open a shell on the Android device and get a listing of ports (`ls /dev/tty*`).

If this is a USB connection, get a listing of ports before and after connecting the XBee so you can identify it's device name (the tty that shows up after connecting the device).

Do you have a terminal emulator on the Android device that you can use for debugging?  Maybe ssh in and use minicom?

Comment: i'm sorry that's not the problem the problem here is the CommPortIdentifier on android code

Comment: Are you using the `getPortIdentifiers()` method to get a list of ports?  Can you provide more details in your original question?

Comment: please look at my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834517/using-the-commportidentifier-on-android